# What does the Schwarz lemma state?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> What does the Schwarz lemma state ?

Apologize, I googled it without success, I only found something related to complex analysis, what I ask is in the theory of PDE. It should state something like; If $w(x,t)$ is the solution of the heat equation, $\partial_tw-\Delta w=0$ then $\partial_x w$ satisfies also the heat equation. Do you know the lemma completely ?